# Understanding the usefulness of Android Async Http Client

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm new to Android and Java and I'm trying to use loopj's Android Async Http Client. I don't understand all the technical nuances of the introduction the library states:  "All requests are made outside of your app’s main UI thread, but any callback logic will be executed on the same thread as the callback was created".

For instance, why is having the callback logic executing on the same thread as it was created important/useful? What is that opposed to? What other alternative threads could the callback logic can be executed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> For instance, why is having the callback logic executing on the same
>   thread as it was created

The main reason it the UI. Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. This means that your application will crash if a different thread tries to update the UI

> What other alternative threads could the callback logic can be
>   executed?

this is strongly implementation-dependent. For instance the callback could be executed on the same thread which performed the async call

Answer (score 1):

I can see that execution happening on the same Thread good for at least one situation. The UI can't be modified from outside the UI Thread, so in the case you make a connection and get some data that you want to display in a EditText it is helpful to have the callback executing on the same UI Thread (Assuming you created the callback in such Thread).